# Do ∃x(Dog(x)) and ∃x(¬Dog(x)) contradict each other?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Formally, ∃x(Dog(x)) and ∃x(¬Dog(x)) look like they contradict each other. However, in the real world,

1. there exist objects which are dogs i.e. ∃x(Dog(x))
2. there exist objects which are not dogs i.e. ∃x(¬Dog(x))

I don't know what I'm getting wrong. I was inspired to ask this question after watching a YouTube video on translating "Not all dogs are happy" to predicate logic. I initially obtained ∃x(Dog(x)∧¬Happy(x)): "there exists an object which is a dog and it's not happy". I'm not sure if this translation is correct either.

Comment: What if Dog(x) is "$x\in \{x\}$" ?

Comment: Depends on what set of objects $x$ is in. For the objects in my home, the two statements are not the same and don't have the same true/false value.

Comment: Both of those statements are true in the real world, and they are not in contradiction with one another. On the other hand, the statements $\exists x(\operatorname{Dog}(x))$ and $\neg\exists x(\operatorname{Dog}(x))$ do contradict each other.

Comment: It is by no means "the same," but it clearly also is by no means (necessarily) "contradictory." As you well note, in a universe with more than $2$ objects, it can perfectly be that $\exists x \ P(x)$ and $\exists x \ \neg P(x)$. The proper negation to "$\exists x \ P(x)$" is "$\forall x \ \neg P(x)$." Stating both of these things at the same time would indeed be contradictory, whereas there are universes where the previous two statements can both hold. Note, however, that an universe consisting of a single element would not be able to verify both of these statements no matter what.

Comment: Two things can both be true without meaning the same.  It's true that there is a dog in the world  and also that there is a cat in the world, but $\text{dog}≠\text{cat}$.

Comment: Why should this be a contradiction ? We do not speak of the same concrete object (for which of course "dog" and "not dog" are contradicting properties.

Comment: FYI  the convention in first-order logic is to represent a predicate, such as "___ is a dog," with a single symbol, such as $D$, and not a string of multiple symbols, such as "Dog." Thus, the propositional function "$x$ is a dog" is represented as $Dx$ or $D(x)$.

Comment: If you find any of the answers below helpful, then please click the corresponding green check mark to close out your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the real world,
>
> 1. there exist objects which are dogs i.e. **∃x(Dog(x))**

In other words: "something is a dog".

> 2. there exist objects which are not dogs i.e. **∃x(¬Dog(x))**

In other words: "not everything is a dog", i.e., **¬∀x(Dog(x))**.

> Formally, ∃x(Dog(x)) and ∃x(¬Dog(x)) look like they contradict each other.

As you have demonstrated above, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are in fact consistent with each other; so, they certainly do not contradict each other.

To be clear: the negation of $(2)$ is **∀x(Dog(x))** rather than $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A contradiction is a well-formed formula of the form

$$P \wedge \neg P $$

So, if we know $P$ and want to derive a statement that contradicts $P$, then we simply need to determine $\neg P$. With this in mind, if we let the proposition $P : \exists x Dx$ where $Dx : $ "$x$ is a dog" and the domain is the set of all things, then

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\neg P \\
\neg \exists x Dx & \text{by definition of $P$} \\
\forall x \neg Dx & \text{by DeMorgan's Law for Quantifiers} \\
\end{array}
$

Hence, the formulas $\exists x Dx$ and $\forall x \neg Dx$ contradict each other. This becomes more apparent when we consider their translations

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\exists x Dx : & \text{There exists at least one $x$ such that $x$ is a dog.} \\
\forall x \neg Dx : & \text{For every $x$, it's not the case that $x$ is a dog.}
\end{array}
$

In short, we're saying "there exists a dog" and "there are no dogs" in the domain, respectively. Obviously, these two formulas are inconsistent, so a conjunction of the two will always be false.

Your translation of "not all dogs are happy" is correct. First, notice the statement is actually the negation of a universal statement stating "all dogs are happy." Given

$
\begin{array}{llll}
Dx: & \text{$x$ is a dog} \\
Hx: & \text{$x$ is happy}
\end{array}
$

we translate "all dogs are happy" as $\forall x [Dx \to Hx]$. In other words, "for every $x$, if $x$ is a dog, then $x$ is happy." The negation of this formula is as follows

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\neg \forall x [Dx \to Hx] \\
\exists x \neg [Dx \to Hx] & \text{DeMorgan's Law for Quantifiers} \\
\exists x \neg [\neg Dx \vee Hx] & \text{Implication Rule} \\
\exists x [\neg\neg Dx \wedge \neg Hx] & \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
\exists x [Dx \wedge \neg Hx] & \text{Double Negation Elimination} \\
\end{array}
$

which reads as "there exists at least one $x$ such that $x$ is a dog and $x$ is not happy."